# C# - Replacing Text in .txt Resource

Tags: c#, text, resources, replace

I was looking at some code from VB.NET and was wondering how I could do this in C#.

```
Dim Source As String = My.Resources.TextFile1.Replace("[TextToReplace]", TextBoxWithInfo.Text)
```

I rewrote this to:

```
string source = myProgramName.Properties.Resources.TextFile1.Replace("[TextToReplace],TextBoxWithInfo.Text)
```

I've also put a text file in with the "Add Resource" feature in Visual Studio. I've then changed "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource" because I want it to be a standalone application. The problem I get though is "myProgramName.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'TextFile1'". Am I looking in the wrong place? I have a feeling it relates to me changing the Build Action but I am not sure on how to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create a text resource named 'TextFile1' in your resource file?

Comment: The resources that you're accessing with the `Properties.Resources.TextFile1` is inside your Resources.resx file.  If you expand "Properties" under your project you should see it.

Comment: That's odd, before whenever I added resource it went into another Resources window called Resource1. After opening Resources.resx I can open a window instead called Resource, which I am able to access. I didn't realize this until now. I probably could access the previous one if I did resource1.TextFile1 instead.